# Why would significance of F-value change in linear regression if you change the reference group?

Tags: regression

For categorical predictors with k levels, it doesnt matter what you choose as your reference group. So why would the F-value significance change in the linear regression if you change the reference group?

Also is it possible for the F-test to not reject the null hypothesis when it really should? When does this happen?

For reference:

```
          The REG Procedure
                                       Model: MODEL1
                      Dependent Variable: HDL HDL cholesterol (mg/dl)

                  Number of Observations Read                       2032
                  Number of Observations Used                       2025
                  Number of Observations with Missing Values           7


                                   Analysis of Variance

                                          Sum of           Mean
      Source                   DF        Squares         Square    F Value    Pr > F

      Model                     4     1380.42472      345.10618       1.89    0.1094
      Error                  2020         368694      182.52193
      Corrected Total        2024         370075


                   Root MSE             13.51007    R-Square     0.0037
                   Dependent Mean       51.47259    Adj R-Sq     0.0018
                   Coeff Var            26.24711











                                       The Reg Procedure
                                       Model: MODEL1
                      Dependent Variable: HDL HDL cholesterol (mg/dl)

                  Number of Observations Read                       2032
                  Number of Observations Used                       2025
                  Number of Observations with Missing Values           7


                                   Analysis of Variance

                                          Sum of           Mean
      Source                   DF        Squares         Square    F Value    Pr > F

      Model                     4     1333.76988      333.44247       1.83    0.1210
      Error                  2020         368741      182.54503
      Corrected Total        2024         370075


                   Root MSE             13.51092    R-Square     0.0036
                   Dependent Mean       51.47259    Adj R-Sq     0.0016
                   Coeff Var            26.24877
```

The first one is with group 1 as reference group. The second is with group 2 as reference group. Note that the two F values are different.

Comment: What group to set reference doesn't matter for significance test for the whole model. But it does matter for the tests of individul predictors (the other groups).

Comment: @ttphns: Then why am I getting different p-values  for the F test depending on the reference group?

Comment: Do you include any interactions?

Comment: @whuber: No I am just testing a dependent variable on 1 independent variable with different levels.

Comment: It might help to give details of the "linear regression."  Important aspects include whether you include a constant and how you encode the groups.  For your second question, investigate [power](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power) related threads.

Comment: @whuber: I am using 1 and 0 as the coding variables. The intercept will be the reference group.

Comment: Are you saying your model is $y =\beta x +\varepsilon$ where $x$ takes on only the values $0$ or $1$ (and $\varepsilon$ is a random error)?

Comment: @whuber: yes. thats right. So the intercept is the reference group. But when I change the reference group the F values changes. So what should I use as the reference group?

Answer (score 2):

The model needs a constant.  In its current form,

$$y =\beta x +\varepsilon,$$

with $x$ constrained to be $0$ or $1$, there are two possibilities.  First, let group "A" be coded as $x=0$ (the "reference" group) and group "B" be coded as $x=1$.  For group A the model is

$$y = \beta 0 + \varepsilon = \varepsilon$$

while for group B it is

$$y = \beta + \varepsilon$$.

Thus, *it assumes the mean value of $y$ in group A is zero,* but it estimates the mean of group B (as $\beta$).  Second, let group A be coded as $x=1$ and group be be coded as $x=0$.  Now the model assumes the mean value of $y$ in group B is zero but estimates the mean of group A.

Neither situation is satisfactory unless one of the group means happens to be close to $0$ (relative to the standard error of the residuals): it has no ability to estimate the mean of the reference group.  The F-tests will differ; whichever reference group has a mean closer to zero ought to yield the smallest p-value.

The solution is to fit

$$y = \alpha + \beta x + \varepsilon;$$

that is, to include a constant in the model.  Now, in group A (with the original coding of $x=0$) the model is

$$y = \alpha + \beta 0 + \varepsilon = \alpha + \varepsilon$$

and in group B it is

$$y = \alpha + \beta 1 + \varepsilon = \alpha + \beta.$$

Whence $\alpha$ estimates the mean of A and $\beta$ estimates the difference in group means.

A pooled t-test will be equivalent to the F-test here: it should yield the same p-value.

Comment: Thanks. But what about for 5 levels of the predictor instead of just 2 (i.e. multivariate linear regression)? Why would the F-test be different for different reference groups?

Comment: @Tom Apply the same analysis: without a constant, you are trying to fit 5 groups using four parameters.  One of the groups--the reference, which won't appear explicitly in the regression output--will have its mean forced to zero.  When its mean truly is close to zero, you're fine, but if you use another group with a markedly nonzero mean for reference, its residuals are large, causing all differences seem to be less significant.  This will be obvious if you plot residuals by group.

Comment: Isn't the intercept in the regression output the intercept? If I get different F-values, should i use the reference group with the  lowest p-value?

Comment: @Tom If there's an intercept in the output, then you're using a constant, your model should be correct, and the *overall* p-value for the regression should not vary.  (But you said you weren't using the constant!)  Perhaps you could clarify this point and also tell us exactly what you understand by "F-values," because maybe you're not referring to the one overall test statistic in the regression, which is what an "F-value" usually means.

Comment: I am referring to the overall test statistic (i.e. if any of the coefficients are significantly different from 0). Suppose $y$ is the dependent variable and the levels of are $x$ are $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 2,\dots, x_5 = 5$. If I do $y$ vs $x_1, \dots x_4$ ($x_5$ is reference group), I get a different overall F value than if I do $y$ vs $x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$ ($x_1$ is reference group). Note that there is an intercept.

Comment: I think I figured it out. The dependent variable had some missing values for various $x$.

Comment: +1 @Tom That would do it.  It's a pity your software did not issue warning messages about its treatment of missing values.  (Often the only intimation you get of a potential issue is by means of a careful look at the value of $N$ in the output.)

Comment: SAS automomatically deletes missing items. So it could be another problem.